# Xcode / Swift | Button changes back to previous position when clicking or typing in a UITextField

Tags: swift, xcode, animation

I have created two UITextFields, named "username" & "password" and a button, named "login" that appear in a second ViewController when clicking on a button in the first ViewController. The login button should move from one position to another, so I implemented that animation in the viewDidAppear function. But every time I write the first letter into the username textField, the button moves back to its old position from the first ViewController. Same happens when clicking first in the username textField and after that in the password textField. 
PS: I created a segue from the first to the second ViewController (Present Modally)

How do I fix that one?

[The viewDidAppear function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPj3g.png)

Comment: Are you using constraints? If so, you should not do animations based on your frame.

Comment: @SanderSaelmans Yes I do, but the when deleting the contsraints for this button, how do I "constrain" it another way or place it like it should?